# How can I split a string in Java?

Tags: java, .net-3.5, split

Imagine I have this string:

```
string thing = "sergio|tapia|gutierrez|21|Boston";
```

In C# I could go:

```
string[] Words = thing.Split('|');
```

Is there something similar in Java?
I *could* use Substring and indexOf methods but it is horribly convoluted. I don't want that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [String.split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String   test = "a|b|c";
String[] splitStr = test.split("\\|"); // {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String thing = "sergio|tapia|gutierrez|21|Boston";
String[] words = thing.split("\\|");
```

The problem with "|" alone, is that, the `split` method takes a regular expression instead of a single character, and the `|` is a regex character which hava to be scaped with `\`

But as you see it is almost identical

Answer (score 3):

I would try the [String.split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, personally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's something similar.

```
String[] words = thing.split("|");
```

Comment: Expect that it takes a regex string, not a char.

Comment: True.  I just checked in the java.util.regex.Pattern class.  It doesn't appear to me that the | character has to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. You just call the split method with a delimiter

String s = "172.16.1.100";

String parts[] = s.split("\\.");

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same : [String.split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.split()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the pipe delimiter with \\, someString.split("\\|");

Comment: No, \\. \ is a string escape character.

Comment: apologies, I didn't realize the stackoverflow software would escape backslashes. my original post had double backslashes, you are of course correct.